# Link "out" of an SVG within an <object>

Tags: html, object, svg, xlink

I am trying to link to a different page from an SVG but the link causes the page to open within the containing  and not the specified page.

Basic samples of my code:

HTML

```
<object data="/Sample.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="Svg">
    <a href="/Sample.svg">
        <!--[if lte IE 8 ]-->
        <p class="SvgFallback">Fallback text</a></p>
    </a>
</object>
```

Link within Sample.svg

```
<a xlink:href="/Page.aspx">
  <tspan x="14.78" y="8.4" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'UniversLTStd-Black'"        font-size="7"> Sample</tspan><tspan x="0" y="16.8" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'UniversLTStd-Black'" font-size="7">page</tspan>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the  like this:

```
<a href="/Sample.svg" target="_top">
```

target specifies where the link should open, _top makes it full-page.

Comment: Im not linking from the <object> in my html, im linking out of the svg <a xlink:href="/Page.aspx"></a>

Comment: Probably xlnk:target="_top" then.

Comment: The attribute to use is `target` even inside the svg, see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/linking.html#AElementTargetAttribute.

Comment: works, I wonder is there a way to achieve this without modifying the svg file ?